# All Music Off iPhone

Tags: music, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S, and I recently upgraded to Spotify Premium (it's awesome) and want to clear all the music off my iPhone (through the normal iPod app).

Thing is, I use iTunes Match so plugging into iTunes won't let me wipe it all out - and there are a lot of artists that I want to delete - it would take a long time.

Is there any way to expedite the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't through the iPod app, but it (should) delete all the music from your device.

Settings > General > Usage > Music > Edit (button, upper right hand corner) > "-" button > Delete.